# Symfony constraint error is not located where it should

Tags: php, forms, validation, annotations, symfony

I have a 'complex' symfony form that let the user choose between an existing address or fill a new one. There are 3 form types:

- The [AddressFieldsType](https://github.com/ruben-podadera/tmp-sf-form-issue/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/AddressFieldsType.php), that handles the address fields like zipCode, etc.
- The [AddressIdType](https://github.com/ruben-podadera/tmp-sf-form-issue/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/AddressIdType.php), that let the user choose an existing Address in the database by entering its id. Yes this is not user friendly. Yes this is just here for explanation reasons, in the real case I have a select.
- The [AddressType](https://github.com/ruben-podadera/tmp-sf-form-issue/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/AddressType.php) that combines the two forms

The AddressType should get/set from/to an Address but its own form description does not match with the data so there is a [data transformer](https://github.com/ruben-podadera/tmp-sf-form-issue/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/AddressTypeTransformer.php) that converts an Address to the excepted data array format.

I made a full symfony project to explain the problem :
https://github.com/ruben-podadera/tmp-sf-form-issue

### No issue:

With this code :

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Address.php
...    
class Address
{
    public $id;

    public $zipCode;
}

// src/AppBundle/Form/AddressFieldsType.php
...
class AddressFieldsType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('zipCode', TextType::class, [
                'constraints' => [new NotBlank()]
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Address::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

I submit empty data :
    address[address_id]:
    address[address_fields][zipCode]:

I get this :

[image]

-> This is correct, the constraint error is located next to the field causing the error

### Issue:

With this code :

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Address.php
...
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Address
{
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    public $zipCode;
}

// src/AppBundle/Form/AddressFieldsType.php
...
class AddressFieldsType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('zipCode', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Address::class
        ]);
    }
}
```

I submit empty data :
    address[address_id]:
    address[address_fields][zipCode]:

I get this :

[image]

-> not correct, the constraint error is on top of the form

### Of course :

In the real project I must use the annotated contraints because they are used by other forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually format your form row like this :

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.zipCode) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.zipCode) }} {# This field will show the error if any #}
    {{ form_widget(form.zipCode) }}
</div>
```

or this way :

```
{{ form_row(form.zipCode) }}
```

Anyway, your issue must be in the formatting of your template.

Comment: Thanks for you help but sorry this did not work (Neither the property "zipCode" nor one of the methods "zipCode()", "getzipCode()"/"iszipCode()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Symfony\Component\Form\FormView").

Comment: could you please provide your template ?

Comment: maybe form.addressFields[0].zipCode ?